# How to mount a tmp directory with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How do you specify a mount volume in docker-compose, so your Dockerfile can access files from it?

I have a docker-compose.yml like:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  app_test:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /tmp/cache:/tmp/cache
```

And in my Dockerfile, I want to access files from `/tmp/cache` via RUN like:

```
RUN cat /tmp/cache/somebinary.tar.gz | processor.sh
```

However, running docker-compose gives me the error:

```
/tmp/cache/somebinary.tar.gz does not exist
```

Even though on the host, `ls /tmp/cache/somebinary.tar.gz` confirms it does exist.

Why is docker-compose/Docker unable to mount or access my host directory?

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile `RUN` commands are executed at build time of the image.

The volume is mounted at run time once the image is run as a container. So the mounted files will not be available until you spawn a container based on your image.

To define the commands to use at run time, use [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), or depending on how you intend your image to be used [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

You would need to add this at the end of your Dockerfile:

```
CMD cat /tmp/cache/somebinary.tar.gz | processor.sh
```

Comment: This is happening during the build process. Using `CMD` is not an option.

Comment: Have you considered using [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)? Why is this not an option?